# awk subsetting on ID's in $1 and close( )

Tags: awk

I am trying to sort with `awk` a large csv file by id's in the first column on OSX.

I started with:

```
awk -F, 'NR>1 {print > ($1 ".sync")}' file.csv
```

However, the process stopped at ID s_17 with the error:

```
awk: s_18.sync makes too many open files input record number 37674601, 
file file.csv source line number 1
```

I tried modifying with this `close()` statement but it then only writes the first file

```
awk -F, 'NR>1 {print > ($1 ".sync");close($1 ".sync"}' file.csv
```

Can anyone provide insight on how to close the files after each one, properly, so that the number of open files stays manageable but they all get written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you close the file you need to use the append `>>` operator so you don't clobber the output files:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR>1{f=$1".sync";print >> f;close(f)}' file.csv
```

Check out the [**manual**](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html) for the official word on redirection with `awk`.

Comment: Just to clarify -  awk -F, 'NR>1 {f=$1 ".sync";print>>f;close(f)}' file.csv

Comment: Just to clarify sudo_O, did you mean:  `awk -F, 'NR>1 {f=$1 ".sync";print>>f;close(f)}' file.csv`  (this does not seem to be working; its only writing a single file

Comment: That will write one file per unique value in the first column of `file.csv`. Post a representative sample file in your question, what version of `awk` are you using and on what platform?

Comment: -I am on OSX mountain lion.  your code is working fine for this simple data Item1,200,0:0:1
Item2,500,0:0:1
Item3,900,0:0:1
Item2,800,0:0:1
Item1,600,0:0:1   , but not my big dataset.  I'll keep plugging away though

Comment: Is only one file created even with the example data set on your system? awk on OSX shouldn't have problem with this, double your input file and the contents of your output file that is created.

Comment: I've made an example file with Item1 - Item20, and three columns and repeats of all of them.  Your code works fine.  Writes 20 different files, and doesn't get hung up.  Still working....

Comment: Then the problem must be with your input file.

Comment: So, this method is working, but it seems to be appending to each file line by line.  Should it be?  I have 133 million rows, 15330 subsets and some subsets with ±4 million rows.  i.e. it took 30 minutes to create the first subset.

Comment: Yes that is correct, of course a large file will take a long time. Please accept this answer by clicking the tick mark next to it if you problem is solved.

Comment: I will accept it, but I just wonder why for subsets less than 18 (OSX limit?), and without the close(), the first 18 subsets get written in a total of 10 minutes.  Why is this close() method slowing down the subsetting so much?

Comment: Because before the file was already open, now for every line in the  a file gets open, has to seek to the end of the file and then closed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't sort with awk. AWK is great to format data before sorting. Pipe the output  into sort(1) and let it sort the data. That's what sort does, and it does a great job.

Also - which type of sort do you need? Dictionary? Numeric? Do you need to ignore spaces?

example:

```
sort -t, -n <file
```

Comment: the data are already sorted. This is definitely a subsetting problem, generating new files out of a large basefile.